# A little moment

Tags: idiomatic-language

Does "**a little moment**" sound natural to a native English speaker? Is there any difference between "**a little moment**" and "**just a moment**"?

The context is about asking someone to wait for a short period of time, as in, "just a moment, please".

Comment: *Just a moment* would be idiomatic, along with *just a mo*, *half a mo*, *just a second*, *just a tick* and a few more but NOT *a little moment*!

Comment: @Ron - Also, "one moment". But I'd like to see more context here. How does the OP envision these phrases being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments *a little moment* is very unnatural. If you're indicating that you have to do something quickly and will return to someone/something else *just a moment* or *one moment* is better.

Comment: It's funny how "in a little while" and "in a little bit" seem fine, and even "in a moment" seems okay, but "in a little moment" sounds decidedly off.

Comment: @J.R. It is. I assume it's due to redundance.